# Написание наречия до...смерти

Tags: орфография

Напугать до смерти или досмерти? 
Я всегда считал, что пишется слитно.

Answer (score 4):

Наречие *до смерти* пишется раздельно.  Ударение на первом слове в наречном сочетании не является условием слитного написания.

Answer (score 3):

Наречие - такая часть речи, словообразование которой ещё не закончилось.Есть наречия, которые пишутся слитно, а есть наречные сочетания, они пока на пути от предложно-именных сочетаний к наречиям.До смерти, на смерть, при смерти - как раз из них. Напуган как? До чего?-до смерти.Быть в каком состоянии? При чём? -при смерти. Бороться не на жизнь, а на что?-на смерть. Пока в сочетании сохраняется возможность управления падежом, это предложное сочетание с сущ.Чаще всего это сочетания с предлогами БЕЗ,ДО,НА,С:без чего?- без удержу, без чего?-без устали,до чего?- до отвала, до чего?- до упаду,на что?-на ощупь Возможно к сущ. подставить определение:на (всём)скаку, на диво(дивное),с размаху - со всего размаху, с ходу- со всего ходу. Всё это говорит о том, что существительное не утратило своих признаков, значит, пока пишется с предлогами раздельно.Но ударение перешло на предлог, в предложении обстоятельство, т.е. выполняет уже роль наречий. Видимо, в скором времени возможен окончательный переход в наречия, по крайней мере, такой вопрос в РАН уже стоит.

Comment: @Людмила, а у какой части речи словообразование *уже закончилось*?

Comment: Я говорю не об отдельном слове, а о самой категории.Совсем недавно учёные спорили о том, самостоятельная ли это часть речи. Некоторые относили её даже к частицам. Сейчас говорят как об оформляющейся самостоятельной части речи, тогда как о других морфологич. категориях никто не спорит, все категории уже оформлены, говорят только о переходе одной в другую, от этого во многом зависит и написание: предлог несмотря(на)и деепрчастие не смотря (на),с наречием это только начинает происходить:сущ. с предл.смотрел на прокат стали и взял напрокат,лучше смотреть в словарь.

Comment: В словарях возле "До смерти" помета - наречие. В учебниках это правописание тоже в теме "Наречие". Все-таки здесь значение "очень", в переносном значении. Если в  прямом смысле до смерти  - вот тогда уж несомненно существительное. Согласна, что если присутствует употребление в разных формах (до смерти, при смерти) - сохраняется раздельное написание.

Comment: Так ведь и я о том же. Это наречное сочетание, т. е. наречие по роли, но правописание осталось от существительного.Когда-нибудь, возможно, будет писаться слитно, чтобы отделить от существительного:до смерти оставалось...

Comment: Ларf, не хотите ответить?  http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/14557/, что-то нет правильного ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если как в песне "... а до смЕрти четыре шага", то, конечно, сущ. и пишется раздельно